# Go http.FileServer gives unexpected 404 error

Tags: go, http, fileserver

I'm trying to run two file servers, one of them serving `index.html` in the `ui` folder, and one other serving some other static files, like the code below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    srv := http.NewServeMux()

    // File server 1
    uiServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./ui"))
    srv.Handle("/", uiServer)

    // File server 2
    staticFilesServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files"))
    srv.Handle("/files", staticFilesServer)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", srv); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Both fileServer objects are defined in the exact same way, and the first one (uiServer) works fine, but the second (staticFilesServer on `localhost:8080/files`), gives me 404.

---

I narrowed down the problem and removed the first one (working file server), just like the code below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    srv := http.NewServeMux()

    staticFilesServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files"))
    srv.Handle("/files", staticFilesServer)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", srv); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

But it still gives me 404 on the path `localhost:8080/files`

---

If I change handle path from `/files` to `/`, it works as expected, but that's not what i want, I just want to know is it even possible to serve on paths other than `/` and how can I achieve that.

---

Also, my folder structure:

```
|- main.go
|- ui
|--- index.html
|- files
|--- file1.txt
|--- file2.csv
|--- file3.img
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that `http.Dir()` and `http.ServeMux.Handle()` would have a relation, they actually sum up their paths, as show below:

```golang
srv.Handle("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))
```

Code above serves everything inside `./files` folder, not `.` (as written in `Dir(".")`)
And it fixed my problem.